# How to fix css and jQuery slide show?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-float

I'm following the slide show example of this [tutorial](http://responsiveslides.com/). The problem I am having is my CSS drop down navigation menu comes underneath this slide show; therefore, those menus are hidden since the navigation menu is sitting right above the slide show. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post any css/html/javascript/pictures of the problem to help us out?

Comment: `z-index` would probably fix it, cant tell for sure since you didnt provide any code or example!

Comment: without code or images, is difficult to help, please improve your question. A link to a tutorial for code referral is frown upon, show the pertinent code here please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you give a z-index value to the Menu's css that is greater than that of the slide shows? E.G:

```
z-index: 999999;
```

Comment: Awesome! That solves my css menu issue. I totally forgot about that. Many thanks for the help!